# Putting a line on a QPushButton

Tags: c++, qt

I am creating a program that draws graphs; I want to be able to have a button that a user can press to choose the line color and style. I want to be able to visually show what the current selection is.

Currently, I know that I can do that using two seperate widgets, a QPush button, and then a widget I make myself that just draws a line across it using QPen.

I would like to turn these two widgets into a single widget. I want this widget to be a pushable "button" that the user presses and I can get a signal out of to run a routine that sets a new QPen.

Is this functionality built in?  Or would I need to create a new widget that re-implements either QPushButton or QActionButton? Or should I just make my widget which listens to mouseclick events on it and create a signal slot from there?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `QLabel`, set the style sheet, and use that as your line on the graph. You could use the bounds of a `QGroupBox` to define x and y axis.

Maybe something like this:

```
yourQLabel.setStyleSheet("QWidget {background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0); color:white; border: 1px solid black;}"); // red with black border
```

Then you can set the height, width and position of the `QLabel` based on values for your graph. Of course this will only work if lines on your graphs are rectangular. If they aren't, then you'll probably have to use something other than `QLabel`.

Use the setGeometry method of `QLabel` to set this.

```
yourQLabel.setGeometry(x, y, width, height);
```

As far as your button, you can do something similar with that if you want. A `QPushButton` also has the `setGeometry` and `setStyleSheet` methods.

If you want to tell your button to do something on click, assuming you have a `QPushButton` object called `myButton`, add this to your header file (.h):

```
class YourClass
{
    Q_OBJECT
    //...
    private slots:
        void on_myButton_clicked();
}
```

Then in your source file (.cpp):

```
void YourClass::on_myButton_clicked()
{
    // stuff your button does on click
}
```

Comment: The graph that I am making is a set of line graphs.  I want the user to be able to choose some attributes about each line, like color, line style (solid, dotted, solid-dot, etc), and line thickness.  And I wanted to be able to show on the button the current line.  Would your solution do this?

Comment: Like I said, my solution would only work with straight lines. If you're trying to make something like this: http://www.mathgoodies.com/lessons/graphs/images/line_example5.jpg then no it will not work. I wasn't sure what sort of graphs you were making.